# how do I create a string that can't be stored in varchar(500) but is a legal nvarchar(500)?

Tags: c#, nvarchar

I want to security test our app. The column and user input text fields are set to maxlength of 500.

currently my attempt at creating such a string is `catalog.Reward_desc=Enumerable.Range(1,500).Select (e =>"ﻷ").Delimit(string.Empty);`

to see if I can get linqpad to let me search for an issue in a general c# sense.

How can I either using c# to create a string to pass into the DAL, or using a string pasted into the input element (on the html page), to make sure that this is being handled properly from front to middle and in the DAL?

**edit -- adding information**

here's sample code where I try to see if I've hit a character that isn't properly storable in that `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collated column:

```
var catalog= new Catalog() { Add_dt=DateTime.Now, Update_dt=DateTime.Now, Reward_name=string.Empty, Reward_image=string.Empty,Add_by=string.Empty,Update_by=string.Empty, Redemption_type_id=1 };

using(var db = new UserQuery(this.Connection)){
db.Catalogs.Max (c => c.Reward_desc.Length).Dump();
this.Connection.Open();
using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    var source=Enumerable.Range(1,500).Select (e =>"€").Delimit(string.Empty);
    catalog.Reward_desc=source;
    catalog.Reward_desc.Length.Dump();
    db.Catalogs.InsertOnSubmit(catalog);


    db.SubmitChanges();
    db.Catalogs.Max (c => c.Reward_desc.Length).Dump();
    var desc=db.Catalogs.Where(c=>c.Reward_catalog_id == catalog.Reward_catalog_id).Select (c => c.Reward_desc).First().Dump();
    (desc==source).Dump();
}
    db.Catalogs.Max (c => c.Reward_desc.Length).Dump();
}
```

Comment: Pick a character that is not representable in the encoding that goes with the collation you've picked for that column.

Comment: managed to trip it with `var source=Enumerable.Range(1,1).Select (e =>'\uFFFE'.ToString()).Delimit(string.Empty);` db is returning the char `63` instead of the value that was given. wonder if copy/paste in a browser would manage to pull this same result off.

Comment: What is `\uFFFE`, and what is `.Delimit(...)`? doing?

Comment: `'\uFFFE'` is the highest was my attempt to put back the data after I modified it to produce the results. I am able to reproduce it with just `'\u0FFF'` Delimit is simple an extension method for `.Aggregate((s1,s2)=>s1+delimiter+s2)`

Comment: also, it's an exclamation mark according to win 8.1's character map, if I'm reading this right, `0FFF` on the other hand is *Latin Letter Small Capital A*

Answer (score 1):

Write a string and then read it back and compare values. If you use non-ansi letters, readed string will most probably be invalid (for example, extended letters will come back as `?`.

Your picked character looks az a good candidate, however, it depends on the 8-bit encoding of the actual database.

Comment: added comment regarding the actual encoding. when you say write a string then read it back, you mean to the database? into a c# string marked with the same encoding? can you provide more detail?

Comment: Read back from the database to a c# string.

Comment: I tried that, also with `€` and neither tripped either a character that wasn't the same on the way out as the way in, nor anything else that looks like I've found a `char` that doesn't store properly in the encoding for that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source=Enumerable.Range(1,500).Select (e =>'\u0FFE'.ToString()).Delimit(string.Empty);
```

is a legal `varchar(500)` but when stored in the db and pulled back out comes out with the high bits truncated. So no exceptions, but truncation sounds like it is dangerous if the browser will submit it this way and c# will run it to the db (passing most validation because it's not containing anything blacklisted by c# checks.)

Comment: looking at the sql under the hood it appears c# isn't really involved much, the db does what it things is best when it gets the paramaterized sql: `DECLARE @p4 VarChar(1000) = N'࿾'`

Comment: which is the int 4094 as a char in c#, I checked the values, nothing is being lost between input and C# at least using linqpad as the DAL rather than going through my integration test.